# Mails going to spam. Please see the details

Tags: postfix, spf, spamassassin, dkim, email

My hostname is properly set up.
Host file has proper entries.
Mail header shows SPF pass.
IP is not balcklisted.
Mail body is also fine.

Only thing don't have is DKIM setup.

Now I have got two domains on the same server. Mails are going to inbox from one domain and to spam from the other one. The other one is a new domain - so no chances that the domain has been marked as spamming domain.

Searching the Internet I found that localhost/127.0.0.1 in the mail header can create problems and also absence of DKIM. But I think in my case it is not that - else mails from both the domains would have gone to spam.

Can anybody help me in finding the problem.

I have Postfix, Dovecot, Amavisd installed. Using Squirrelmail. Server is running on Ubuntu 12.04

Below are the Mail Headers.

Working header:

```
x-store-info:7YsnRco0gQJ3EyekdHv0zlwbSFmh6T19OKG2DRa1LmMeJxgQn9G9daCVjxHTsWMJwpb2etzRAJxKhZtUNYv5S5RsM10528BoXPAgw37zh+mdEjmglV3TbqC8MzZd864j+qmai+dU3Xg=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 106.187.99.77) smtp.mailfrom=admin@kolkataonweb.com; dkim=none header.d=kolkataonweb.com; x-hmca=pass header.id=admin@kolkataonweb.com
X-SID-PRA: admin@kolkataonweb.com
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MTtHRD0yO1NDTD0w
X-Message-Info: NhFq/7gR1vTbh6GeR4A77FFvq26uYbApmtayJTspM6NE6ojfcCRXKgmUwuuCSuH/f1I+30q4S8f4EWWAeXg3E+GbKLrVtBXyWYFmzlvelmtn7H6+5LiCFtnKtM/1aCHHGoTJoIsbIdKVW+Sbe3D5N0Pl/SXj90jMtsYsL+HZtDbYGZw2tZDJeIqXOPBgtPWu6Sqt7Bxq8f1w3kLX3vzDm0LV3wcQL7ta
Received: from unicorn.kolkataonweb.com ([106.187.99.77]) by BAY004-MC2F29.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.22712);
     Mon, 4 Aug 2014 15:01:09 -0700
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by unicorn.kolkataonweb.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 8694E12926
    for <manish_ind00@hotmail.com>; Tue,  5 Aug 2014 03:31:08 +0530 (IST)
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at unicorn.kolkataonweb.com
Received: from unicorn.kolkataonweb.com ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (unicorn.kolkataonweb.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id KnBsc9IujCYe for <manish_ind00@hotmail.com>;
    Tue,  5 Aug 2014 03:31:08 +0530 (IST)
Received: from kolkataonweb.com (localhost [IPv6:::1])
    by unicorn.kolkataonweb.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 538A312925
    for <manish_ind00@hotmail.com>; Tue,  5 Aug 2014 03:31:08 +0530 (IST)
Received: from 115.253.74.8
        (SquirrelMail authenticated user admin@kolkataonweb.com)
        by kolkataonweb.com with HTTP;
        Tue, 5 Aug 2014 03:31:08 +0530
Message-ID: <0668f04a7cc8369d266e583cb6d2d34c.squirrel@kolkataonweb.com>
Date: Tue, 5 Aug 2014 03:31:08 +0530
Subject: Test
From: admin@kolkataonweb.com
To: "Manish Mandal" <manish_ind00@hotmail.com>
User-Agent: SquirrelMail/1.4.23 [SVN]
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Importance: Normal
Return-Path: admin@kolkataonweb.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 04 Aug 2014 22:01:09.0729 (UTC) FILETIME=[9933BD10:01CFB02F]
```

Non Working Header:

```
x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kRyU+pBy2R9QCDI9u8Kc1JelXzetVs2jxqzkjAYPLy37kFX3uWvhbpReT+kd3FNPdHDodYhyNaiuBe10IjgJ9uVS+uLoSKBU3VnG6jNOpx113ilW3cGTstfg=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 106.187.99.77) smtp.mailfrom=admin@spiderlogfreight.com; dkim=none header.d=spiderlogfreight.com; x-hmca=pass header.id=admin@spiderlogfreight.com
X-SID-PRA: admin@spiderlogfreight.com
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD02
X-Message-Info: 11chDOWqoTmFs/JCKWDdHfyt50oGuNWdrq+ZjF1wJeqx44/1d8KbOOCwFI5312PKnGJKsZC7qrMJsKeoHk7igYCb/Mw5gduTIVHRorJNtJBDoCM5JmSJ6+VZdGiuuiCfnPRGIbFZ/kUBdYiuUl3jCV6ug7b/Xa6STzjnW2MTPHoVYP30qKrqPX7QsOcsyPR3nsszwenC8bDxjFxdILM1hU1tnjC7oz1D
Received: from unicorn.kolkataonweb.com ([106.187.99.77]) by SNT004-MC3F50.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.22712);
     Thu, 7 Aug 2014 00:43:45 -0700
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by unicorn.kolkataonweb.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 049AD12939
    for <manish_ind00@hotmail.com>; Thu,  7 Aug 2014 13:13:44 +0530 (IST)
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at unicorn.kolkataonweb.com
Received: from unicorn.kolkataonweb.com ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (unicorn.kolkataonweb.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id gNpy4ovixRqU for <manish_ind00@hotmail.com>;
    Thu,  7 Aug 2014 13:13:43 +0530 (IST)
Received: from www.spiderlogfreight.com (localhost [IPv6:::1])
    by unicorn.kolkataonweb.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 64FC912938
    for <manish_ind00@hotmail.com>; Thu,  7 Aug 2014 13:13:43 +0530 (IST)
Received: from 115.243.65.157
        (SquirrelMail authenticated user admin@spiderlogfreight.com)
        by www.spiderlogfreight.com with HTTP;
        Thu, 7 Aug 2014 13:13:43 +0530
Message-ID: <da89873a3ea363091be2ea0076676fba.squirrel@www.spiderlogfreight.com>
Date: Thu, 7 Aug 2014 13:13:43 +0530
Subject: Meeting On Friday
From: admin@spiderlogfreight.com
To: manish_ind00@hotmail.com
User-Agent: SquirrelMail/1.4.23 [SVN]
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Importance: Normal
Return-Path: admin@spiderlogfreight.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 07 Aug 2014 07:43:45.0611 (UTC) FILETIME=[515B89B0:01CFB213]
```

Comment: @MadHatter I have checked the post, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.
First I have almost all the points covered, except the DKIM. 

My question was

Comment: Firstly, you didn't say what research you'd already done, so we couldn't know that; it's polite to spend more of your time writing a question, to avoid us spending more time writing answers.  Secondly, that answer is canonical; that means it's all the community chooses to say on the subject.  However, others might not agree with me; if this question doesn't get closed, it may yet attract an answer.

Comment: @MadHatter, well actually as it happens part of reply got truncated because of time limit. Here is the rest.

I have checked the post, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.

I have almost all the points (mentioned in that post) covered, except the DKIM and very good rating of IP (mine is 1.5 out of 5). 

If those two points were the problem then won't both the mails go to spam?

I have checked and re-checked all possibilities 100 times, I think I am missing something very subtle OR something which most of the articles on internet didn't say.

Comment: @MadHatter as I cannot add a lot of text here, I have answered each point in that post you mentioned, so if you be kind enough to take a look and help me if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sole difference here is the domain, focus on that:

1. It is newly registered, and has not had time to build up a good reputation.
2. It is newly registered, and that in and of itself is often an indicator of spam. Spammers often register domains with stolen credit cards, start spamming immediately, and then several days later the domain gets canceled when the cardholder disputes the charges. A domain that is a few weeks old doesn't raise nearly as many red flags as a domain that is a few days old.
3. You should also be aware that as of this moment, both domains are coming up SERVFAIL. Take a peek at your DNS and fix it. Not your hosts file, but rather your DNS.
4. Fix your DNS and then give it time, this issue will most likely resolve itself once your domain is a bit older.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe. I didn't know that domain needs time. I guess you are right - the domain whose mails are going to inbox is many years old, it had a functional website till few weeks back and once had good traffic. 
Yes, at the moment the domains are down, trying to fix things - I messed up settings - fixing them at the moment.